Create new column and add row value based on string in existing column using data.table
Because I can't quite find what I am looking for on stack, I decided to write my first question! If I do something wrong, apologies in advance.
I work with large datasets which I cannot share publically, so I have created a simplified, short version of my data below called my_dt:
> library(data.table)
> id <- 1:5                             # Vector 1                           
> temp <- c(10,12,11,13,12)             # Vector 2                    
> date <- c('2010-03-01','2010-04-01',  # Vector 3
+           '2010-05-01', '2010-06-01',
+           '2010-07-01')       
> my_dt <- data.table(id, temp, date)   # Create data.table
> my_dt
   id temp       date
1:  1   10 2010-03-01
2:  2   12 2010-04-01
3:  3   11 2010-05-01
4:  4   13 2010-06-01
5:  5   12 2010-07-01

Using data.table, I want to create a new column called *month * and extract the month string from *date *(the middle value, because character format is YYYY-MM-DD), and input this into the new column e.g. for row 1 (date = 2010-03-01), I want month = 3.
I worked out a line of code which works for a single month (see below), but if you run it manually for each month consecutively, it removes what you input previously:
> my_dt[, month:= ''][grepl("-03-", date), month:=3] 
> my_dt
   id temp       date month
1:  1   10 2010-03-01     3
2:  2   12 2010-04-01      
3:  3   11 2010-05-01      
4:  4   13 2010-06-01      
5:  5   12 2010-07-01      
> my_dt[, month:= ''][grepl("-04-", date), month:=4] 
> my_dt
   id temp       date month
1:  1   10 2010-03-01      
2:  2   12 2010-04-01     4
3:  3   11 2010-05-01      
4:  4   13 2010-06-01      
5:  5   12 2010-07-01   

Does anyone know of an efficient and automated way of doing this, without removing previous *month * entries, so I can apply it to a large dataset (>80000 rows)? Perhaps a loop which runs through months 1:12?
Thanks in advance!

The issue is that the code month := '' is setting the month to blank for all rows, before calculating the month for the selected row. You can extract the month from the date string with gsub() instead and get the value for all rows.
my_dt[, month := as.numeric(gsub("\\d{4}-(\\d\\d)-\\d\\d", "\\1", date))]
my_dt
      id  temp       date month
   <int> <num>     <char> <num>
1:     1    10 2010-03-01     3
2:     2    12 2010-04-01     4
3:     3    11 2010-05-01     5
4:     4    13 2010-06-01     6
5:     5    12 2010-07-01     7


You can extract all characters from position 6 to 7 and convert into integer number.
my_dt[, month := as.integer(substr(date, 6, 7))]

      id  temp       date month
   <int> <num>     <char> <int>
1:     1    10 2010-03-01     3
2:     2    12 2010-04-01     4
3:     3    11 2010-05-01     5
4:     4    13 2010-06-01     6
5:     5    12 2010-07-01     7


You  definitely don't want to use use loop to scan the column 12 times with grepl(). Here is a concise way with data.table's inbuilt month() function:
my_dt[, month := month(date)]

#       id  temp       date month
#    <int> <num>     <char> <int>
# 1:     1    10 2010-03-01     3
# 2:     2    12 2010-04-01     4
# 3:     3    11 2010-05-01     5
# 4:     4    13 2010-06-01     6
# 5:     5    12 2010-07-01     7

